# React Hook Form: SetValue does not work properly after reseting the form using reset() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

There are 2 date fields(transactionDate and documentDate) on change of transaction date other one should be updated automatically. Which i am able to do using setValue function from useForm.

I have a used case where on change of a dropdown i have to reset the from which i am able to do by using reset function. But after the form is reset, onChange of transactionDate i update the value for documentDate using setValue and this doesn't work.

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-framework-pi4ot?file=/src/App.js) is the sample code.

This issue I am facing in react hook form v7.10.1

Comment: and if you remove the ´useEffect´ with the reset(), it works, its not?

Comment: It works.. You can try it https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-framework-pi4ot?file=/src/App.js

Comment: that codesanbox is the same of above, you updated it?

Comment: That is same feel free to fork and edit it.

Comment: you only need to remove reset().

Comment: Its not just about reset... what i have given is just a sample code to reproduce the issue. the actual scenario is described in question. I have to use reset there.